# How to read and load an object from a odd type of text file

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, parsing, streamreader

I have been given a file to read and load the properties of an object

The file seems not to be a standard format it just has text sections indicate the properties; I was expecting a sort of xml file format.

Does anyone know this type of file and how to read it?

If not I suppose I will need a StreamReader and check line by line for the "-- " and build up the object from there.

each property has a "-- textlable" and then comes assigning of the value to the objects property. e.g.

```
-- about
        xobject.something.attributes.about.Size = 1.50
        xobject.something.attributes.about.Weight = 16.00

-- location
        xobject.something.attributes.location.address = "text string"
        xobject.something.attributes.location.type = "A"

-- hierarchical 
    -- properties
        xobject.something.attributes.hierarchical.properties = 100.00

        -- another
            xobject.something.attributes.hierarchical.properties.another
```

you get the idea.

Comment: I'm not aware of an off-the-shelf serializer that handles this format.  Seems to be proprietary.  You could consider writing code to transform it into something like JSON and then using an existing serializer, but probably the same level of effort to just parse the file and set the values yourself.

Comment: it looks like the -- lines are comments so you could (as you say) just read the file line by line and ignore blank lines and lines starting --.  This doesn't look like any format I've seen before.